# Generic Type that has annotation entity

Tags: java, generics, jpa, entity

Suppose I have an entity like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
@Entity
class Person{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to make a typed class that should only be applied to classes with the annotation `@Entity`. Something like

```
public class EntityService<T hasAnnotation Entity> {
    ...
}
```

Which would be instantiated like:

```
new EntityService(Person);
```

Is there a way to achieve this? `implements Entity` doesn't work (this gives an error when trying to instantiate the service).

Comment: You could create an annotation with `ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER` and use it to annotate the type parameter `EntityService<@HasEntity T>`, but then you have to write the entire annotation processor to reject bad usage during compilation. This is non trivial. Otherwise, the language doesn't provide anything to do this.

Comment: thank you. if you write it as an answer i could mark it solved, since "the language doesn't provide anything to do this" is enough for me :)

Comment: Is this still not possible?
How would one solve that?